# How to redirect a .py file with GET variable to .php using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect `/download.py?fileId=1` to `/download.php?fileId=1` using .htaccess. Here's what I've tried without success:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/download\.py(.+) /download.php$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/download\.py$ /download.php
```

Query string is automatically carried over to new URI.